# Theme attributes in color selector for API <22

Tags: android, android-theme, android-selector, android-attributes

I have a few color selectors like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

These color selectors work fine for API 23 and above. For API 22 `?attr/colorAccent` doesn't seem to work. I always see a `Red` color instead. this works when not used in a `selector`. Ideally it is suppose to work for API 21+

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior for Pre-Lollipop, since it was added in lollipop (see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36941443)). For compatibility, you can create multiple files for your drawable for your multiple themes.

Comment: yeah but 21 and 22 are Lolipop. I am not even supporting pre-lollipop in my app

Comment: What I mean was, It causes a fatal crash on below API 21. Are you sure you are using the corrent theme and `colorAccent` is defined in your theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can create selector programmatically. Use for this `ColorStateList`.

```
val states = arrayOf(
        intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked),
        intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked),
        )

val colors = intArrayOf(colorAccent, colorWhite)

val selectorColors = ColorStateList(STATES, colors)
```

You can get the colors through `context.withStyledAttributes()`